# Change Postion icon in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left

in my NavigationDrawer i add icon to my list but i cant change position to left .

my NavigationDrawer xml :

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:title="صفحه اصلی"
      android:id="@+id/menuitem1"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:title="درباره ما"
      android:id="@+id/menuitem2"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/newclassicon2"/></menu>
```

my NavigationView xml :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

[image]

Comment: please add your layout.xml file.

Comment: Did you create layout-ar folder in drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here first get a **Locale** and set in **preference** and create **layout-ar** folder in **drawable** folder and create a four same file of one layout and put two file in simple **layout** and rest two put in **layout-ar** folder mentioned below.

**Adapter of nevigation drawer**:-

```
 mainSettinglanguage = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_MAIN_SETTING_LANGUAGE, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.MAIN_SETTING_LANGUAGE);
        if (mainSettinglanguage != null && mainSettinglanguage.equals("ar")) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.section_list_item_ar, viewGroup, false);
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.section_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        }
```

**layout--> item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_section_check"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_section_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chk_section"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/view_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout-ar --> item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_section_check"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_section_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chk_section"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/view_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout --> view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_section_check"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_section_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chk_section"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/view_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-ar --> view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_section_check"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_section_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chk_section"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="AAA"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/view_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this may helps you.